# VueJS set elements property dynamically

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to be able to set a required property of an input element to true while dynamically rendering a list of elements - if that list item has a setting that it is required.
eg:

```
<input name="input" type="{{input.type}}" class="form-control" v-model="dataset.values[name]" placeholder="{{input.placeholder}}">
```

In angular 1 I could use:

```
ng-required="input.required"
```

I couldn't find an equivalent in VueJS, any idea how I could acomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy, just use `v-bind:attribute` (or the shorthand `:attribute`)

```
<input name="input"
       :type="input.type"
       class="form-control"
       v-model="dataset.values[name]"
       :placeholder="input.placeholder"
       :required="input.required">
```

Comment: Thanks, as a beginner I prefer writing v-bind: and all the other non shorthand versions.